# Vf page to display the related record Not working as expected

Tags: visualforce

I've `Assessment` object is Parent and `outcome` object is Child. I'm displaying the assessment recrod in page block table and when I click on assessment record I've to display the related outcome(child) records.

As per requiremnt I'm using the Id of assesment record in the browser URL of Page. like `?id= a1G29000000lpk8`

I've implemented the logic for my requirement but it is not wokrinig as expected.

When i click on the assesment record it always passing the id which is avaialbe in URL, not passing the id of record on which I clicked.

VF page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Assessment__c" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" extensions="cntr1test">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Outcome" id="Outcomed" columns="1" collapsible="true">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Asses}" var="b">
                <apex:column headerValue="Last Screening">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!OutcomeList}" reRender="outpnl" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!b.id}" />
                           <apex:param name="id" assignTo="{!asmntID}" value="{!b.id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>    

<apex:pageBlock id="collapseSec">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Outcomes" id="d" columns="1" collapsible="true">
            <apex:outputPanel id="outpnl" >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relatedout}" var="c" rendered="{!showoutcome}" >
                   <apex:column headerValue="Id" value="{!c.id}"/>
                   <apex:column headerValue="firstname" value="{!c.Name}"/>

               </apex:pageBlockTable>
           </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class cntr1test {

private List<Assessment__c> asses;
Assessment__c assment;
Assessment__c AssRec;
public ID asmntID{get;set;} 
public Outcome__c outcome{get;set;}

public cntr1test(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.assment= (Assessment__c)controller.getRecord();
    outcome = new Outcome__c ();
//here is query to fetch the record bases of the Id present in the URL 
//I'm using fields in this query in further part of logic. 
    AssRec= [select id,Name,Patient__r.Name from Assessment__c where Id=:assment.Id]; 
}

public List<Assessment__c> getAsses()
{
    asses = [Select id,Assessment_Description__c,Last_Screening__c,Date_Due__c, Resolved__c,Delete__c,Type__c,Sort__c,RT_Type__c,Outcome_Count__c,Create_Outcome__c from Assessment__c where Resolved__c=false];
    return asses;
}

public List<Outcome__c> relatedout{get;set;} 
public boolean showoutcome{get;set;}
public void OutcomeList(){
    system.debug('@@@'+asmntID); 
    relatedout = [Select id,Name from Outcome__c where Assessment_Number__c=:asmntID];
    system.debug('@@@'+relatedout);
    showoutcome=relatedout.size()>0?true:false;
}
}
```

Comment: which id is coming in system.debug ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Id available in the browser URL. `?id= a1G29000000lpk8`

Comment: are you able to get assessment__c object when pageload or Outcome__c (relatedout )  is not getting load ?

Comment: @NITHESHK yes. I'm getting `assesment` object on page load. & after page load when i click on  assesment record, I want to dispaly related outcome record.

Comment: system.debug('@@@'+asmntID);  are you getting asmntID which you have click ?

Comment: @NITHESHK No. at  
system.debug('@@@'+asmntID); getting ` a1G29000000lpk8` which is avaialbe in  `https://salesforce.visual.force.com/apex/amolDemo?id=a1G29000000lolp`

Comment: system.debug('@@@'+relatedout); getting excepted result here ?

Comment: @NITHESHK  system.debug('@@@'+relatedout); Getting record realted to id `a1G2900‌​0000lolp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68066/discussion-between-nithesh-k-and-amol).

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace with this code.few change i have made with form tag and commandlink.

```
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockSection title="Outcome" id="Outcomed" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Asses}" var="b">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Last Screening">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!OutcomeList}" reRender="collapseSec" value="{!b.id}" >
                               <apex:param name="id" assignTo="{!asmntID}" value="{!b.id}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock id="collapseSec">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Outcomes" id="d" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                <apex:outputPanel id="outpnl" >
                   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relatedout}" var="c" rendered="{!showoutcome}" >
                       <apex:column headerValue="Id" value="{!c.id}"/>
                       <apex:column headerValue="firstname" value="{!c.Name}"/>
                   </apex:pageBlockTable>
               </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but same issue. for this link `https://c.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/demo` it is working perfect and for this link `https://c.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/account_contact_related?id=a1G29000000lolp` not working expected.

Comment: if i am not wrong understood your question, You are passing assessment id in the url, and  display the assessment__c object of related id.   When you click on the assessment__c.id , Your are displaying all list of  Outcome__c which is related assessment__c.id.  right ? everything isfine according to your code. what problem again your facing ? , when your passing different assessment__c.id your are not able to display all list of  Outcome__c ?

Comment: it slightly different as per you understanding, by the way I've copied another code and it worked. Not sure whats wrong, I will find out in extra time.